# Broadcom STA update broke WiFi

Tags: wireless, 12.04, broadcom

I have the BCM43225 chip in my Acer Aspire One netbook running 12.04 32-bit.  My wireless had been working just fine (with the exception of enterprise networks not being able to connect to the internet...but that is another story) until I updated the Broadcom STA wireless driver a couple days ago.

Ever since, the wireless will randomly disconnect from the network ever half hour or so and take around a minute or two to reconnect.  Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: look at this post it may help.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/130477/dell-upgrade-to-12-04-lts-no-wifi-and-bluetooth-problem/132693#132693

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4312](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Broadcom B43xxx.  Disable the STA driver, reboot, connect the Ethernet cable to get to the Internet, and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/129611/567) to the respective question, which is very similar to yours.

The only difference I could find (I am the author of the linked question and answer) was that the interruptions were a lot more frequent in my case, but perhaps the problem is the same one. It seems that the 12.04 upgrade brought problems to many of the Broadcom network card users.