# BCM43142 wireless card drops connection after some time

Tags: 14.04, networking, broadcom

I know this question has been discussed in this forum but there is no concrete answer it seems. I have BCM43142 wireless card in my HP desktop(Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS). Wifi works fine but after some time(after 6+ hours) - connection gets very slow and finally doesn't work.

```
# lspci | grep -i network
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Gone thru this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and run the [wireless script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and here is the output

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 21 Feb 2016 19:27 MST -0700

Booted last: 21 Feb 2016 19:15 MST -0700

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-49-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 11:24:31 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2af3]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2230]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0458:0146 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0461:4e24 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6369280  0 
hp_wmi                 16384  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
cfg80211              524288  1 wl
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'docker0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'vmnet1' [IF]>  
          inet addr:172.16.170.1  Bcast:172.16.170.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'vmnet8' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.172.1  Bcast:192.168.172.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:61457 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:19547
          TX packets:41711 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:71225715 (71.2 MB)  TX bytes:18230947 (18.2 MB)
          Interrupt:19 

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

vmnet1    no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

vmnet8    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"TP-LINK_536C"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'TP-LINK_536C' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=72 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
172.16.170.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.172.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1269     1  0 19:15 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [TP-LINK_536C] ------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            wl
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           72 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    Nitin:           Infra, <MAC 'Nitin' [AC5]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 94 WPA WPA2
    0493E6:          Infra, <MAC '0493E6' [AC2]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 89 WPA WPA2
    ChacheNetwork:   Infra, <MAC 'ChacheNetwork' [AC4]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 79 WPA WPA2
    HOME-EE12:       Infra, <MAC 'HOME-EE12' [AC3]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 75 WPA WPA2
    Satnam_N:        Infra, <MAC 'Satnam_N' [AN5]>, Freq 2427 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 70 WPA2
    1C1106:          Infra, <MAC '1C1106' [AC6]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 55 WPA WPA2
    *TP-LINK_536C:   Infra, <MAC 'TP-LINK_536C' [AC1]>, Freq 2417 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 81 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.105
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TP-LINK_536C]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TP-LINK_536C | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=TP-LINK_536C
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TP-LINK_536C 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TP-LINK_536C 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=TP-LINK_536C | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Phoenix (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

vmnet1    no frequency information.

docker0   no frequency information.

vmnet8    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     26 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Channel 157 : 5.785 GHz
          Channel 161 : 5.805 GHz
          Channel 165 : 5.825 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

vmnet1    Interface doesn't support scanning.

docker0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

vmnet8    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      3   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'TP-LINK_536C' [AC1]>
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"TP-LINK_536C"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 48ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC '0493E6' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"0493E6"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 48ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'HOME-EE12' [AC3]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"HOME-EE12"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 48ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'ChacheNetwork' [AC4]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ChacheNetwork"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 48ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'Nitin' [AC5]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Nitin"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 48ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC '1C1106' [AC6]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=45/70  Signal level=-65 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"1C1106"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 48ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     9A49255BA90267D99664757
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-49-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     EF182B558008C23DD85EF03
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A9:32:DC:23:78:95:A4:4D:39:59:BF:91:A3:56:6A:20:EE:21:1F:37
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf]
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-kms.conf]
options nouveau modeset=0
options nouveau modeset=0

[/etc/modprobe.d/vmware-fuse.conf]
alias char-major-10-229 fuse

##### rc.local ##########################

/opt/redislabs/sbin/systune.sh
exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4365 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   30.353103] bridge-wlan0: device is wireless, enabling SMAC
[   30.353105] bridge-wlan0: up
[   30.353107] bridge-wlan0: attached

########## wireless info END ############
```

Also gone thru these threads:
[T1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594114/problem-with-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless-driver-on-14-04)
[T2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529347/how-do-i-keep-my-wifi-from-dropping-out)
[T3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128024/wireless-connection-is-lost-periodically-and-without-apparent-reason-and-is-quic)

But doesn't seem to work in my case. I need to reboot the system after every 6-8 hours.

And here is my settings-->Additional Driver
[image]
As per that i am using the right driver but why it disconnects after 6-8 hours?

Comment: I'm using a Lenovo G510 laptop, but I get the exact same output from the lspci command, as you, which must mean I have the same type of network controller. I'm using the proprietary driver with good results, the one suggested in `Settings - Additional Drivers`.

Comment: @theodorn. Edited original question and added my additional drivers.